# wpf DataGrid disable cell edit for specific row except first column

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a binding to a generic `DataTable` where some rows may contain problems and should not be modified. There seems to be a very easy way to accomplish that by simple setting `IsEnabled` in `DataGrid_LoadingRow` or by a `Trigger` with `Binding` in `XAML`.
However, I also have a “Info”-Column which has a Button in it so that the user can view the problem… Setting IsEnabled to false also disables my button…
I already tried: `IsManipulationEnabled` but this has no effect.
How can I accomplish this? Is the only way for doing that by traversing the `VisualTree` of the `DataRowView` and set `IsEnabled` for all Cells except the first?

Comment: How you are checking if those some rows have problems ? Rest is easy to achieve.

Comment: When I create the DataTable I add a special column for that information.

Comment: Ok, let me do it now.

Comment: To be more specific. I'm loading data wich is controled by a version control system. When I build the DataTable I check if the ID of the current object is in the list of checked out ones... If so I want to disable every column except the first one in DataGrid so that the user can view some information e.g. who has checked it out...

Comment: For me it seems to work when I evaluate the value of first column in: DataGridControl_BeginningEdit and set Cancel to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first column, use this `Button`,

```
public class EnabledButton : Button
{
    static EnabledButton()
    {
        UIElement.IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(EnabledButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None,
                    UIElement.IsEnabledProperty.DefaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback,
                    new CoerceValueCallback(IsEnabledCoerceCallback)));
    }

    private static object IsEnabledCoerceCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return (bool)baseValue;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:EnabledButton IsEnabled="True" Content="Modify"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This overrides the inheritance of `DataGridCell.IsEnabled` property.

Comment: Awesome! 1000 Thanks!